# Is it possible to send uniform data to a struct in GLSL with one function call

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to send uniform data to a struct with one `glUniform` function call instead of having to individually setting the components of the struct with multiple `glUniform` function calls?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to upload aggregations of values (outside of arrays of basic types) to a uniform in a single function call. If you need to upload bulk uniform data, it's best done via UBOs.

Comment: would it be possible to uniform an array of floats to the location of the struct?

Comment: @SaadAmin: "Uniform" is not a verb; you cannot "uniform" something. Are you talking about uploading it? Because I just said that you can't. There isn't even such a thing as a "location" for a uniform of a struct type; there are only locations for the members of a struct. Just call the function for each member, or use a UBO if you prefer.

Comment: yes I mean uploading it. I mean the first member of the struct